# How to do PostgreSQL between + interval query from Django 1.8?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, view

I have a PostgreSQL query which generates a view that buckets only the first 30 days of data into the view.

```
CREATE view vet_visits_over_first_30_days AS
(SELECT veterinarian_session.animal_id AS "animal", veterinarian_account.enrollment_date AS "Enrolled", veterinarian_sessionactivity.created_date AS "Admit Date", veterinarian_sessionactivity.detail AS "Reason" 
FROM veterinarian_account, veterinarian_sessionactivity, veterinarian_session 
WHERE veterinarian_sessionactivity.created_date BETWEEN veterinarian_account.enrollment_date AND veterinarian_account.enrollment_date + '30 days'::INTERVAL AND veterinarian_sessionactivity.activity_sub_id=52 AND veterinarian_sessionactivity.session_id = veterinarian_session.id AND veterinarian_session.animal_id=veterinarian_account.id 
ORDER BY veterinarian_session.animal_id);
```

which will then let me do:

```
select * from vet_visits_over_first_30_days;
```

and get back only the visits in the first 30 days.

Does Django 1.8 have a way to do these BETWEEN queries using '30 days'::INTERVAL or do I need to use raw SQL?

I'm aware that there's an interval field in Django 1.8 but I don't need to store the interval, just use it to generate the view.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#durationfield